# Initialize database in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am a beginner of `Flask`, I am reading the book `Flask Web Development`.

My question is why we do not need `__init__` to initialize the following classes in models.py

**Example 5-2. hello.py: Role and User model definition**

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role {name}>'.format(self.name)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {username}>'.format(self.username) 

>>> from hello import Role, User
>>> admin_role = Role(name='Admin')
>>> user_john = User(username='john')
```

Comment: what do you want to put in `__init__` ? You can use `__init__` if you really need.